# Swift: Core data trouble with to-many relationship and mutableOrderedSetValueForKey

Tags: swift, core-data, nsorderedset, nsmutableorderedset

I'm having trouble understanding why my ordered set is only saving 1 entry.

my code is as follows:

```
let newInovice = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Invoice", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! InvoiceMO

let itemDetail = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("InvoiceDetail", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! InvoiceDetailMO

    // Data Entry

    // Add invoice number to Invoice
    newInovice.invoiceNumber = getInvoiceNum()
    newInovice.date = invoiceDate
    // Create mutable set to add details
    for items in details {
        itemDetail.detail = items[PropKeys.itemDescription]
        let item = items[PropKeys.itemPrice] ?? "0"
        let itemDouble = {  return Double(item) ?? 0  }()
        itemDetail.price = itemDouble
        let quantity = items[PropKeys.itemQuantity] ?? "1"
        let quantityInt = {  return Int(quantity) ?? 0  }()
        itemDetail.quantity = quantityInt
        print("This is the item detail before insertion: \(itemDetail)")
        newInovice.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("invoiceDetails").addObject(itemDetail)
        subtotal += itemDouble * Double(quantityInt)
    }
    print("details.Count = \(details.count)")
    print("Start Mutable  \(newInovice.invoiceDetails?.count) End Mutable Set")


    // Save the Data
    do {
        try newCustomer.managedObjectContext?.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

I've read through the docs and it seems like I'm doing this correctly but it only adds one entry to the ordered set even though I've iterated through the array of objects.

Here is my debugger showing the entries before they are added and the count of the managed object after adding the objects.
[debuggerWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXcKU.png)

my relationships are set up as follows:
[relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXjdB.jpg)

Comment: You can also set the relationship in the opposite way: `itemDetail.invoice = newInovice`

Comment: can you check that you're not adding the same object all over again? I mean, can you check that `itemDetail` is different from the previous one?

Comment: I did see it done this way in the docs and have implemented it in my code now. Much cleaner, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating one `InvoiceDetail` outside your `for` loop. Obviously, you will have to create one for each detail that is contained in the data array.

Comment: Thank you @Mundi!!  That was it!  I just moved the line `itemDetail = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("InvoiceDetail", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! InvoiceDetailMO` into the loop and poof, it's doing what it should.